# Script to fix onelined markdown

Tags: regex, text, replace, sed, tr

I am looking for help with fixing markdown. I have many files written in markdown, however all of them are in one line, eg:

```
'''Tittle''' - there is some text. ==Heading== {{Image|l=http://exaple.com}} ==References== *[http://www.example.com] *some text here
```

To make this files work I have to enter new line before every special character, eg:

```
'''Tittle''' - there is some text.

==Heading==

{{Image|l=http://exaple.com}}
Some more text.

==References==

*[http://www.example.com]
*some text here
```

I am looking for way to automate this process, can someone help me with writing RegEx for this, or at least explain which tool is best for use with it?

Comment: do you have == before start of every field?

Comment: Special characters are: ==text==, ===text===, =text=, *text, '''text''', ''text'', but I think, I can edit RegEx if I see example

Comment: Can you have `'''title == foo'''` situations?

Comment: No. Also, it's markdown from some MediaWiki website.

Comment: How are your markdown files getting "corrupted" like this? It seems you should try to prevent whatever is causing the "one-liner-ing" of the source files.

Comment: There are exported pages from MediaWiki, I get them from someone else, no idea why it's corrupted like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the following:

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]\(=\|{{\|\*\|'\''\)/\n\1/g' your_one_line_file
```

This considers the special sequences `=`, `==`, `===`, `{{`, `*`, `'`, `''`, `'''`, but only when they follow a space or newline or tab, etc. It then breaks the line replacing that "space" with a newline character.

Careful when you escape the single quote: it has to be done outside of the quotes enclosing the **sed** script, that I close and then reopen.

#### EDIT

After Kuba's clarification/request, and to allow spaces at the end of the string enclosed by the special sequences, we write a script (writing it into a file lifts the burden of escaping cleverly the `'` character) that has pattern-matching lines using the `\1` reference in the pattern itself to detect the closing special sequence. So please write the following script into a file, e.g. `sedscr`:

```
s/[[:space:]](=+)([^=]*)\1/\n\1\2\1/g
s/[[:space:]]('+)([^']*)\1/\n\1\2\1/g
s/[[:space:]]\{\{([^}]*)\}\}/\n{{\1}}/g
s/[[:space:]]\*/\n*/g
```

And then run the script on your one-line file with the `-r` option because I use extended regexps to make the script a bit shorter (using the `+` metacharacter):

```
sed -r -f sedscr your_one_line_file
```

Comment: It's not correct - It puts newline also before closing `==`

Comment: Sure, but only if there is a space immediately before that closing `==` (or any other special sequence).

Comment: See my edited solution, as it takes care of that issue.